# Insert data to mysql database from CSV file and there is a double input for the data in the last row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Please correct my PHP code. I tried to insert a CSV file into my MySQL database, but there is double input for data in the last row.

example of my csv data :

```
csv
----------
1
2
3
4

mysql
----------
1
2
3
4
4
```

Code:

```php
if(isset($_POST["upload"]))
{
    if($_FILES['import_data']['name'])
    {
        $filename = explode("." , $_FILES['import_data']['name']);
        if(end($filename) == "csv")
        {
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['import_data']['tmp_name'], "r");
            while($data = fgetcsv($handle,null,';'))
            {
                $NO = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data[0]);
                $DATA 1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data[1]);
                ...

                $sql = "INSERT INTO $ID (ID, DATA 1, DATA 2, DATA 3, DATA 4, DATA 5, DATA 6) VALUES ($NO, '$DATA 1' ,'$DATA 2', '$DATA 3', '$DATA 4', '$DATA 5', '$DATA 6')";

                mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            }
}

if(isset($_GET["updation"]))
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly that the last row of the CSV file contains two rows worth of data?

Comment: I tried to edit my csv data format but it didnt work. also i've edited my question to show the example data of my problem